# How can I make downloadable file created by XmlDocument()

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have created a file with

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
```

Can I make this file as downloadable? without saving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<xml>myxml</xml>");
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=MyXmlDocument.xml");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", doc.OuterXml.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.Write(doc.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

```
xmldoc.Save(Response.OutputStream)
```

Don't forget to set response mime type and other relevant properties so client browser will understand it as a file download.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to respond to a request for it, saving the document to the response. Of course, you'll need to be able to *get* the `XmlDocument` somehow - if you've created it in one request (e.g. for a page) you'll need to either be able to recreate it based on parameters, of cache it in the session (with all the normal caveats).

For an example of writing it out, within a normal `Page` you might do:

```
xmldoc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

or

```
xmldoc.Save(Response.Output);
```

You can easily create a .ashx file and associated code-behind (new "Generic Handler" item) and then in the code-behind which implements `IHttpHandler` implement `ProcessRequest` with:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    XmlDocument doc = ...;

    doc.Save(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

You may also want to set an appropriate content type (probably "text/xml" unless it's a specific XML format which you'd want to be interpreted differently) etc. If you want the client to default to saving it, you should set a content disposition.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at writing a **Custom HTTP Handler** (a class that implements `IHttpHandler`) and simply register it in web.config. See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx) for a good example of how to set one up.

Here's a basic example of how you might go about implementing one to return the markup for an `XmlDocument`.

```
using System.Web;

public class MyXmlDocumentHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public static XmlDocument XmlDoc
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyXmlDocumentHandler()
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; // Set the MIME type.
        XmlDoc.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream); // Write the XML markup to the respone stream.
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // To enable pooling, return true here.
        // This keeps the handler in memory.
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Differently from what Noldorin posted you don't have to create a Custom HTTP Handler.

If you want to download the XML document created by the XmlDocument class, you can always save it directly to the stream, setting its content type to `text/xml`.

More or less like the following code:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

/*
 * ... more code ...
 */

this.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

xmldoc.Save(this.Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: You don't have to register a custom handler, but I've found it easiest to create a .ashx file (+code-behind) which writes the appropriate XML. I prefer that to using a normal page which one might expect to create HTML.